# NMM Error "Error loading the following mods" Fallout 4

Tags: fallout-4, mods, nexus-mod-manager

when I try to open the NMM it shows me an error window saying "Error loading the following mods:" then it lists the path to every mod ( http://prnt.sc/czljvv ). I have an option to choose just OK and then I get a new error message titled "missing mods" and it just goes insert mod name cannot be found, however, a different version has been detected. The installed missing version is XXX and the new version is XXX (exactly the same version). It asks me if i want to upgrade the mod and when i press yes it goes to the next mod, and when i press yes again it opens the next message(too long to write): *can't post link cause I have low reputation* I press yes and choose Fallout 4 and choose the path to my mods and press finish and it goes back to the beginning of this thread.

I posted this on reddit and someone answered with:
First thing to check is the your E: actually exists. If it's an external drive it's possible Windows changed the letter. If the drive does exist make sure the path is correct and exists. If that is true then you should run a disk check. Right click on the drive in Windows Explorer and choose properties, goto Tools, and run the Check under Error Checking.
If your E: doesn't exist (because the letter was changed or something) then you'll need to tell NMM where to find the files now.

And that is my answer:
I've checked a few times and yes it is E: and the path is good, windows didn't change a thing. I've ran the scan and it said everything is fine. I don't remember how but a few days ago when I posted this on a different forum I got a tracelog (?): *can't post more than 2 links cause I have low reputation*

I still need help.

Comment: You have Fallout 4 on your C drive, and mods on your E drive? That's a somewhat dangerous thing to do, but make sure NMM has multi-drive mode enabled. I don't remember off the top of my head where it is, but I remember seeing a setting for it when I set up SkyrimSE.

Comment: I see you checked to see if that location exists. My question is have you checked to make sure that the entire path is spelled correctly? You may have changed a folder name and didn't notice it. I would post as an answer but this is just pure speculation.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, here's what I've discovered. The current version of NMM (I'm on 63.6, not the newest) there is an option to enable Multi-HD Install mode.

[image: Multi-HD Mode]

This can be found by choosing your game, and once the main NMM program loads, click the Wrench and Screwdriver symbol, and click on "Change Virtual Folders." Check the box next to "Enable Multi-HD install mode", and give that a shot. Theoretically, it should solve your issue.

Comment: Ok I did that and it assk for the required link and even if i choose the same hard drive or even the same folder as my games' folder it doesn't work, it keeps saying that it's not in the right place.

Comment: @yonifinkelson You may just need to rebuild your mods folder. Again, modding is not an exact science, and if you didn't have Multi-HD mode enabled to begin with, you should rebuild with is enabled.

Comment: how exactly? @Kaizerwolf I just need to uninstall all mods and reinstall them?

Comment: That would be a good idea, yes. You may even need to reinitialize the entire Fallout 4 mod folder/location. Essentially, start from scratch.

Comment: I reinstalled NMM and the problem consists, any suggestions? Will manually deleting all of my mods help?

Comment: @yonifinkelson Yes, that was my point; disable all of your mods, uninstall them all, uninstall NMM, reinstall NMM, setup Multi-HD mode, reinstall mods.

Comment: I can't even enter the NMM that's the problem, I can't disable anything or uninstall them, just find where they are and delete them.

Comment: @yonifinkelson At this point, you may just want to do a clean install of Fallout 4 and NMM. Once you uninstall Fallout 4, just clear out the folder of any remaining mod data files. Then reinstall Fallout 4 and NMM, enable Multi-HD mode, and install your mods again.